# Ошибка синтаксиса на PHP 7.1

Tags: php

Подскажите, почему получаю ошибку на PHP 7.1

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Ругается на строку:

> if (strpos(($childs[0])->nodeValue, $propName) !== false)
>   Вот весь код

```
if (!function_exists('getPropValueFromHtmlByName')) {
        function getPropValueFromHtmlByName($html, $propName) {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($html);

        $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $childs = $tag->getElementsByTagName('span');
            if (strpos(($childs[0])->nodeValue, $propName) !== false)
                    return ($childs[1])->nodeValue;
        }  

        return '';
    }
}
```

UPD: в $childs[0]

```
object(DOMElement)#617 (18) {
  ["tagName"]=>
  string(4) "span"
  ["schemaTypeInfo"]=>
  NULL
  ["nodeName"]=>
  string(4) "span"
  ["nodeValue"]=>
  string(12) "Availability"
  ["nodeType"]=>
  int(1)
  ["parentNode"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["childNodes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["firstChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["lastChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["previousSibling"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["nextSibling"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["attributes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["ownerDocument"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["namespaceURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["prefix"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["localName"]=>
  string(4) "span"
  ["baseURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["textContent"]=>
  string(12) "Availability"
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте так: `if (strpos($childs[0]->nodeValue, $propName) !== false)`.

Comment: Что в `$childs[0]`? Распечатайте var_dump'ом

Comment: @rjhdby? добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Rootware, спасибо все работает. Оформляйте как ответ)

Comment: @Batyabest на самом деле и со скобками работает в PHP 7.0+, вы уверены, что не в PHP5 запускаете?

Comment: @rjhdby какая цель использовать там скобки? что за новая фича php?

Comment: @tCode специальной цели никакой. Просто это совершенно валидный код для 7+ и он работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы обрамили скобками переменную содержащую объект и после попытались взять из этой конструкции свойства объекта.

Правильнее использовать так:

```
if (strpos($childs[0]->nodeValue, $propName) !== false)
```